# button click onListener and go to different xml layout

Tags: java, oop

I would like to click a save button and go to a different layout file(layout_save).
I got an error message on the Button.on Click Listener() and says that con not be resolve to a type.

Here is my codes;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_final_project);

    Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new Button.onClickListener(){
        public void onClick(view v){
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_save);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Is it the button click listener specifically that can not be resolved to a type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to specify the instance of the onclicklistener inside the setOnClickListener method. All you need to do is just instantiate a new on click listener like this.

```
buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_save);

        }
    });
```

The onclicklistner already knows what instance it is from the set method.

Comment: I did that but this time i got three red marks on onClickListener , setOnClickListener, and view

Comment: What do the red marks say? Hover your mouse over them until a pop up message will show telling whats wrong.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments 
  (new onClickListener(){})
 - Button.onClickListener cannot be resolved to a type
 - onClickListener cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Can you copy and paste your code again? I think you might have misunderstood it.

Comment: @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_final_project);
  
  Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){
   public void onClick(view v){
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_save);
    
   }
  });

Comment: You need to capitalize View in the public void onClick method

Comment: That worked but i still have red marks on onclicklistener and setonclicklistener. Many tanks for your help.

Comment: Click the red line and see if an import option shows up. If so, double click the import option. Otherwise tell me what error you get.

Comment: There is no import, I did the import for View. The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new onClickListener(){})

Comment: The new OnclickListener instance inside the setOnClickListener method needs to have the O capitalized.

Comment: Works great. I did capital O and imported.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try creating an `Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityThatSaves.class)` where this is whatever activity you are on and ActivityThatSaves is whatever activity that is tied to your XML layout that you want to display. Then, call `startActivity(i)`